# Math w/italics in normal context, roman when in italic context (ie, caption)

Tags: math-mode, floats, captions

I have not found this question asked previously.

I am fine with math using italics for variables when the math appears in a normal context. But our figure captions are in italics, and when math is used in a caption, we need to flip all math italics to Roman and vice versa.

I know how to do this by using `\mathrm{}` and `\mathit{}`, but if we have a caption like, say,

```
\begin{figure}  
\caption{As $|\Psi(x_0,t)|^2$ represents yadayada and $x_0$ blah at time $t$, it is clear that foobazz.}  
\end{figure}
```

that's something like eight mathematical elements that have to be manually defined to Roman or italics. Get a dozen or so figure captions like this and things are error-prone, never mind being a PITA.

So: is there a way to get `amsmath` to invert it's normal italics/Roman behavior when inside a caption?

Comment: in your question you refer to `\mathit` (which is a text italic font, used in math) but your examples just have `$x$` which is the math italic font (which isn't the same thing at all). The usual model is that math alphabets carry semantic meaning and latex goes to some effort to ensure they do _not_ change with the surrounding text style, so what you ask is of course possible (it's open source anything can be changed) it isn't really how it is designed to work.

Comment: You could define a new mathversion which uses other fonts, but you really should do it as David already pointed out. Math fonts carry meaning. I also wouldn't write captions in italics: italics emphasize and so are not a good choice for "side" information.

Comment: I naturally meant "you really should *not* do it ...".

Comment: Part of the point of using italics in math is to emphasize the difference between the math and the surrounding text. If the surrounding text is italics, the italics generated by $x$ doesn't emphasize anything at all.

Comment: Telling me not to use italics in captions is not very helpful. This is house style at the journal for which I prepare manuscript, and has been so for a couple of decades.

Comment: I have a book typeset with that style; the typesetting is as awful as the contents: probably the worst math book I have on my shelves. `;-)`

Comment: @PeterCastine I don't understand. Is this a camera ready journal? If not and they accept TeX submissions then they presumably have macros that do this which ypu could use? otherwise if they are going to re-typeset it anyway why emulate this bizarre style in the tex manuscript?

Comment: @PeterCastine: an acceptable solution would be, in my opinion, to use the `\sansmath` (from the ` sansmath` package) command in captions: formulae would be clearly distinct from text fonts, while still being italicised.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I wrote "the journal for which I prepare manuscript." I didn't write "camera-ready copy." Ergo, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: so yes, the math is going to be set by a compositor. But to prevent misunderstandings, we try to prepare the MS as close to the final house printing style as possible. Otherwise we have to insert endless instructions (markup), which is another major pain in the arse.

Comment: Stack Exchange was supposed to be the place to go to get help with LaTeX problems. I've asked a question and all I've had are opinionated, arrogant, unhelpful responses. To Ulrike Fischer and egreg: if I wanted your opinions on style, I'd have asked for them. If you don't have anything to add, then stop wasting your time and mine before I give you the response you deserve. Have I made myself clear?

Comment: @PeterCastine it's not intended to be arrogant or opinionated  but just making it clear that to do what you ask really and make the math fonts context sensitive would mean redefining all of latex's math font handling and is really more code than to be expected in an answer here. Apart from anything else we wanted to check that is _really_ what you meant before anyone started coding.

Comment: Just seen this. "to get help with LaTeX problems": not only LaTeX problems, but also with style problems. We're not arrogant here, although we have strong opinions, and many of us are inclined to ask "why so ugly when it can be really beautiful with LaTeX". You're not the first, and you won't be the last.

Comment: I tried to understand this from the comments but I'm still not sure, so I rather ask: **Are you supposed to have upright math in italic context or you only want to?** If you are supposed to, then leave it to the typesetter. If you want to then simply: ***PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS.*** *Why? because math is font-sensitive, and `$\mathrm{f}$`, `$f$` and `$\bm f$` do mean different things in general.*

Comment: I am supposed to do this.

Comment: …and "leave it to the typesetter" is not always an effective option.

Answer (score 4):

## Do not do this!

You can use the **deprecated** macros `\rm` and `\it` to switch between families.

This is one of the ugliest things I've ever seen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,etoolbox}
\captionsetup{font=it}
\everymath{\it}
\preto\caption{\everymath{\rm}}
\begin{document}
As $|\Psi(x_0,t)|^2$ represents yadayada and $x_0$ blah at time $t$, it is clear that foobazz.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{As $|\Psi(x_0,t)|^2$ represents yadayada and $x_0$ blah at time $t$, it is clear that foobazz.}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
  \captionof{figure}{As $|\Psi(x_0,t)|^2$ represents yadayada and $x_0$ blah at time $t$, it is clear that foobazz.}
\end{center}

As $|\Psi(x_0,t)|^2$ represents yadayada and $x_0$ blah at time $t$, it is clear that foobazz.
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Step in the right direction, thanks. But numbers (and anything else that is Roman in a Roman context) need to be italicized in the italics context.

Comment: @PeterCastine See my updated answer. Please don't do this!